# PHP sessions cannot be retrieved from Memcached by NodeJS

Tags: php, node.js, session, memcached

I have an Apache2 web server running PHP5, which is configured to store it's sessions in memcached (on localhost). Alongside, I have a NodeJS server, running only socket.io (and no http server), and I try to retrieve the PHP session data in NodeJS, using Memcached extension. Here's some (very very simplified) code: http://pastebin.com/ZUZN89Bt
The problem is the console shows: "trying to retrieve data... data not ok: false" many times, meaning I don't get any data from Memcached from NodeJS! (client-side, the Session ID I recieve is OK, I checked the cookies)
When I telnet Memcached and monitor what happens, here's what I get:

```
<29 new auto-negotiating client connection
29: Client using the ascii protocol
<29 add memc.sess.key.lock.7ajh4ne9r9n542b6vuf8efgri4 0 1406208867 1
>29 STORED
<29 get memc.sess.key.7ajh4ne9r9n542b6vuf8efgri4<br>
>29 END
<29 set memc.sess.key.7ajh4ne9r9n542b6vuf8efgri4 0 1440 0
>29 STORED
<29 delete memc.sess.key.lock.7ajh4ne9r9n542b6vuf8efgri4
>29 DELETED
<29 quit
<29 connection closed.
```

(this repeats each time I reload the page)
Where does this problem come from? 
Why can't I retrieve data from Memcached?

Comment: can you try isolating the code that fetches data from memcached? http://pastebin.com/wFwUc5wJ
`sessions.get(some_PHPSESSID, function(err, data) {    console.log(err, data);
}`

Comment: which npm module are you using to connect to memcached?

Comment: I use the [Memcached](https://www.npmjs.org/package/memcached) module to connect to it. I'll try putting only the code that fetches data from memcached, and I'll comment again when done